# DNS queries to compromise DNS cache

Tags: dns, dns-spoofing

The transaction ID for DNS queries can take values from 1 to 65,536 and my computer pseudorandomly chooses one for each DNS request. If I sents 1,024 false replies per request, how many requests should I trigger to compromise the DNS cache with probability 99%? or as close tot hat as I can get. Thanks

I'm getting a result of .6 requests which doesn't seem right to me. Feel as though it should be around 30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your calculation seems to be simplified. According to the formula given in [RFC 5452](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5452), the number of fake packets 'F' that are candidates to be accepted is given by :

P_s  =  D * R * W / ( N * P * I )

where I is the number distinct IDs available (which is 65536 in your case), P is the number of ports used, N is the number of authoritative nameservers for a domain, R is the number of packets sent per second by the attacker, W is the window of opportunity, in seconds and D is the average number of identical outstanding queries of a resolver (typically 1, see Section 5).

If D = 1 (typical value according to the RFC), W = 0.1 (typical value according to the RFC),  N =  2.5 (average value according to the RFC), P = 1 (assume only one port is used) and I = 65536 (provided in your question). Then P_s can be simplified into :

P_s =  R / 1638400

Thus, plugging in the necessary values, for P_s to be 0.99, R should be greater than 1622016 packets/s. Since we used W = 0.1 and you send 1024 false replies per request, then you need about 1622016 * 0.1 / 1024 = 15.84 attempts.

(*Hope my calculation is correct*)

Comment: The final calculation comes out to 158.4 attempts not 15.84